# web3.eth.contract not working

Tags: web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain, nodejs

I have web3@0.20.2 installed using npm . when I call web3.eth.contract() it says that it is not a function and when I use new web3.eth.contract it says it is neither a constructor. This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input name="choice" type="text"> Vote: </input>
<button id="submit">Submit : </button>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }

// Previous if/else statement removed for brevity

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var vote=  web3.eth.contract([
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "c4",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "c2",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "c1",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "x",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "set",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "c0",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "get",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "c5",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "c3",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
],'0x1def5958505131be74680211266cd0667b3fc75d');

console.log(vote);


</script>
</html>
```

Please can someoneone find error in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web [v0.20](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) creating a reference to an existing instance should be done in two steps

```
// Create contract object
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

// Reference instance
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're actually on web3 v1.x, in which case, you should indeed be using `new web3.eth.Contract`, but with a capital `C`.

In order to verify which version of web3 you're on, run `npm ls web3` from a command line or `console.log(web3.version)` from your JS code.

Comment: Done ! Not working constructor is used in web3@1.2.x or 1.0.0 ! it was used as a function in 0.20.6 ! Am i right ?

Comment: @Somilgupta: See updated answer.

Comment: PS C:\Users\somil\attempt> npm ls web3
attempt@1.0.0 C:\Users\somil\attempt
`-- web3@0.20.2

Comment: @Somilgupta: Are you trying to tell me something here? Because if you do, then it is unreadable!

Comment: i was just trying to tell you  its web3@0.20.2 . But i ll try as constructor too tysm !! if it doesnt work i ll get back to you !

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor

Comment: please help if you know about this error !

Comment: @Somilgupta: Either one of `web3.eth.contract` or `new web3.eth.Contract` should work. Can you please `console.log(web3.version)` right before that line?

Comment: {api: "0.20.2", getNode: ƒ, getNetwork: ƒ, …} by using console.log(web3.version)

Comment: @Somilgupta: Are you sure that you previously do `web3 = new Web3(...)`?

Comment: Thank You so much ! its working now ! it was used to be as a function !! thank you so much @goodvibration !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Web3@0.2x.x`, you can look at [API Documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) how to create a contract object and initiate it on an address.